# How to set the default filename in a JFileChooser that accepts only directory?

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I've got a little problem with my application because it needs to save some files in a directory chosen by the user by the (very simple) class DirSaveChooser:

```
public class DirSaveChooser extends JFileChooser{

    private int result = ERROR_OPTION;


    public DirSaveChooser(File file){

        setDialogTitle("Select directory");
        setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

        setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

        setSelectedFile(file);

        result = showSaveDialog(new JFrame());
    }
}
```

I want to set the suggested filename (eg. "new_untitled_dir") using the method setSelectedFile(File), but this is possible only if I remove the:

```
setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
```

I don't like this solution because I don't wanna see also the files in the dialog.

How can I do this?

**SOLUTION**
I've added a simple method in the constructor to find the JTextField (ok, is not a great solution but it works):

```
JTextField text_field = findTextField(this);
if(text_field != null)
    text_field.setText("new_untitled_dir");
```

And:

```
private JTextField findTextField(JComponent parent){

    for(Component comp : parent.getComponents()){

        if(comp instanceof JTextField)
            return (JTextField) comp;

        if(comp instanceof JComponent){
            JComponent jcomp = (JComponent) comp;
            JTextField text_field = findTextField(jcomp);
            if(text_field != null)
                return text_field;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried javax.swing.JFileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(File)

Comment: Yes, but is the same